# Conditional summation

Tags: summation, core-language, sequence

I am a fairly new user to Mathematica and I am strugling with one problem.

I would like to run a simulation to figure it out how long the sequence of $\frac{1}{n}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty $ needs to be, for its summation to achieve 200.

$\sum_{n=1}^{k}{\frac{1}{n}} \ge 200$

I am not as familiar with Mathematica coding. My code so far looks like this:

```
i = 0
n = 1
While[i < 200, i = ((1/n) + (1/(n + 1)))]; n++]
```

I would appreciate the help with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear[m]
```

The partial sum is the definition of the [**`HarmonicNumber`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HarmonicNumber.html)

```
h[m_] = Sum[1/n, {n, 1, m}]

(*  HarmonicNumber[m]  *)
```

An alternate representation is

```
h[m] // FunctionExpand

(*  EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, 1 + m]  *)
```

To find the value of `m` for which the sum is `200`

```
soln = Solve[h[m] == 200, m][[1]] // N // Quiet

(*  {m -> 4.0570915001197426*^86}  *)

h[m] /. soln

(*  200.  *)
```

Comment: Yeah, I was gonna say that running a while loop to figure this out might take a while as the number of terms will be ridiculously large.

Comment: I didn't know how to use a Mathematica syntax and running a loop in R didn't get me anywhere. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

You can get it accurately using `FindInstance`:

```
FindInstance[HarmonicNumber[k] == 200, k]
```

> {{k -> Root[{-200 + HarmonicNumber[#1] &, 
>        4.05709150011974242417272921508*10^86}]}}

Note that `HarmonicNumber[k]` is simply the sum up to k:

```
Sum[1/n, {n, k}]
```

> HarmonicNumber[k]

So your answer is `4.05709150011974242417272921508*10^86` and change!

Answer (score 5):

The correct solutions have already been given. It might be interesting that you can solve the problem with a pocket calculator to a high degree of accuracy using the formula

$$\sum _{n=1}^m \frac{1}{n}\simeq \log (m)+\gamma$$

Where $\gamma$ is the Mathematica constant EulerGamma which has the value

```
EulerGamma // N

(* Out[79]= 0.577216 *)
```

We find the index by solving $\log (m)+\gamma =200$ for `m`

```
mm = m /. N[Solve[EulerGamma + Log[m] == 200], 12][[1]]

(* Out[77]= 4.05709150012*10^86 *)
```

(This can obviously be done with a pocket calculator).

Checking

```
Sum[1/n, {n, 1, m}] /. m -> mm

(* Out[78]= 200.000000000000 *)
```

Remark: The order of magnitude (power of 10) is simply given by ignoring $\gamma$ to be

```
Exp[200] // N

(* Out[81]= 7.22597*10^86 *)
```